# How to pull from a string into first, middle, and last name. And how to recognize when there is no middle name inputed

Tags: java

I need to do the following:

Many documents use a specific format for a person's name. Write a program whose input is: firstName middleName lastName, and whose output is: lastName, firstName middleInitial.

[image]

It's through a textbook so I haven't been taught how to split strings. That's all I can find online, but that's not what the textbook is asking for. So far I've been taught how to compare strings, get a strings length, branches, switch statements, string operations.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      String firstName;
      String middleName;
      String lastName;
      String name;

      name = scnr.nextLine();

      int firstSpace = name.indexOf(" ");
      firstName = name.substring(0, firstSpace);

      int secondSpace = name.indexOf(" ", firstSpace + 1);

      if (secondSpace < 0) { 
         lastName = name.substring(firstSpace);
         System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
      }
      else {
         middleName = name.substring(firstSpace, secondSpace);
         lastName = name.substring(secondSpace);
         System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleName.charAt(0) + ".");
      }

   }
}
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: What should happen when there isn't one of those entered?

Comment: It gives me an error and says " your program expects input"

Comment: No I mean what do you want to happen if you don't enter one of them?

Comment: Oh, if there is no middle name then it needs to print lastName, firstName

Comment: I believe what it wants me to do is use indexOf(), to find the space and then again for the last name.

Comment: Some people's name is a single word -- no first/last. Some people's name includes Jr, Dr. III. Some people have many middle names, not just a single word. Some people's first name is two words (e.g. Billy Joe). The premise that you can split names this way is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 1):

Be simple!!!

All you need here is split given string and count the words (2 or 3) and print the name in the reuired format.

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] arr = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+");

if (arr.length == 3) {
    String firstName = arr[0];
    String middleName = arr[1];
    String lastName = arr[2];
    System.out.format("%s, %s, %s.\n",
                      lastName, firstName, middleName.charAt(0));
} else if (arr.length == 2) {
    String firstName = arr[0];
    String lastName = arr[1];
    System.out.format("%s, %s\n", lastName, firstName);
} else
    System.err.println("Unknown name format");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use the `split()` you can read the first two entries with `scnr.next()` and then the third input will be the rest of the line, and then you can take a substring of it taking the space off.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name1;
        String name2;
        String name3;

        name1 = scnr.next();
        name2 = scnr.next();
        name3 = scnr.nextLine();

        if (name3.equals("")){
            System.out.println(name2 + ", " + name1);
        }
        else{
            name3 = name3.substring(1);
            System.out.println(name3 + ", " + name1 + " " + name2.charAt(0) + ".");
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I know that's the way to do it, but since I haven't been taught split yet, it won't work. But this is very similar to what I have so far, its just not pulling the middle name correctly, I'll update the top with what I have so you can see.

Comment: Oh, glad you found an answer yourself, I edited mine with a code that does not use `split()` btw.

Comment: @JessicaGarnica, I advise you to take your correct code from the question and post an answer with it, it would not make sense ask a question with the solution on it

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

  String firstName;
  String middleName;
  String lastName;
  String name;

  name = scnr.nextLine();

  int firstSpace = name.indexOf(" ");
  firstName = name.substring(0, firstSpace);

  int secondSpace = name.indexOf(" ", firstSpace + 1);

  if (secondSpace < 0) { 
     lastName = name.substring(firstSpace + 1);
     System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
  }
  else {
     middleName = name.substring(firstSpace, secondSpace);
     lastName = name.substring(secondSpace + 1);
     System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName + " " +     middleName.charAt(1) + ".");
  }



  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't provide code-dump homework answers; instead, suggest an approach such as "look for the number of spaces in the string".