# Java string splitting issue

Tags: java, string, split, collections

String name = "Chris Mike Soloman Miller Cooper";
I want to split this string to firstname=(first word), lastname=(last word), middlename=(remaining all words). how can I do it without using for loop. Any java 8 feature to implement here ?
Desired ans:
firstname = Chris, lastname = Cooper, middlename = Mike Soloman Miller
I have tried this but I don't want to use for loop.

```
String name = "Chris Mike Soloman Miller Cooper";
String [] fullName = name.split(" ");
String firstName = fullName[0];
String lastName = fullName[fullName.length-1];
StringBuilder middleName = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=1; i<fullName.length-1; i++) {
    middleName.append(fullName[i]);
    middleName.append(" ");
}
```

String middleName =
String.valueOf(middleName.toString().trim());

Comment: You are looking for [String.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and [String.lastIndexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)).

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411197/how-to-pull-from-a-string-into-first-middle-and-last-name-and-how-to-recogniz) might be of use to your particular case.

Comment: Mandatory read: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: What about "Joe Michael Parker Jr", is the last name "Jr"?

Comment: `name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" ")) + name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(" "));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chaosfire has stated, it's possible to use `String.indexOf()` and `String.lastIndexOf()` to search for where the first and last spaces are. After that, it's just a matter of using those indexes to break the original string into substrings.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Enrico \"The Goat\" Fermi";
        int firstBreak = name.indexOf(" ");
        int lastBreak = name.lastIndexOf(" ");

        System.out.println(name.substring(0, firstBreak)); // first name
        System.out.println(name.substring(firstBreak + 1, lastBreak)); // middle name
        System.out.println(name.substring(lastBreak + 1)); // last name
    }
}
```